# Read data from firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase database, but when I run the code it display nothing, though no errors shown

I got this piece of code from Firebase manual, by the way, I'm pretty sure that the path is correct

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("users").child("user").child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let score = value?["score"] as? String ?? ""
        print(score)

        // ...
    }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

JSON

```
{
  "users" : {
    "user" : {
      "e1410kokeZS8xv81J1RzhN4V2852" : {
        "email" : "aaaa@gmail.com",
        "score" : 0,
        "username" : "Afnan"
      },
      "jPx8XJ3Q9AazDM7qIOhz02PBfh22" : {
        "email" : "aaaa@ggg.com",
        "score" : 13,
        "username" : "ghhh"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Firebase structure? Also Are you expecting score of specific username?

Comment: I edited my question for the JSON structure. Yes I want to retrieve a score for a specific user, username is a variable that hold the ID of that user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are listening for the `.value` event, but your block is dealing with a single item at a time so use `.childAdded` event for that.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("user").child(username)

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
     if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
          //Do not cast print it directly may be score is Int not string
          print(userDict["score"]) 
     }
})
```

**Note:** In Swift use native `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`

Comment: still displaying nothing, I got this in the console: <Warning> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03428] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "username" at /users/user to your security rules for better performance

Comment: it is a random generated ID, sorry for this confusing variable

Comment: @Yousefhumdan What is the log for `print(snapshot.value)`?

Comment: when I print the score in a textfield it failed, what should I do?

Comment: @What do you mean by `it failed` edit your question with your current code and what it is failing with it.

Comment: when I print the score in a text field like this: self.resultLabel.text = finalResult as! String ___ i got this error: Could not cast value of type '_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber' (0x100bc7d20) to 'NSString' (0x1b2065398).

Comment: Write like this way `self.resultLabel.text = "\(finalResult)"` or `self.resultLabel.text = String(finalResult)`

Comment: "\(finalResult)" this way worked but it types the score like this Optional(5), how can I get rid of this optional word?

Comment: Try like `if let score = finalResult { self.resultLabel.text = "\(score)" }`