# Retrieving user info from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I know this question is asked a lot, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me(I have been trying multiple solutions from threads like [Read data from firebase swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933105/read-data-from-firebase-swift) but it doesnt print anything to my console). 
I am trying to retrieve the type of user from my database, but I dont know how to.

```
func pushUserInfo(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let infoDict = ["First name": firstName.text!, "Last name": lastName.text!, "hours": 0, "isUser" : "user"] as [String : Any]
    let users = ref.child("users").child(username)
    users.setValue(infoDict)
}
```

The part that says ["type": "user"] has two options, either "user" or admin
[image]

The screenshot above is of the Firebase realtime database.
I am trying to retrieve the type of the user, but I have no idea how.  Please help me figure this out, and if possible, explain the code, because I dont really understand too much about Firebase in general. I tried reading their firebase docs, but I still dont really get it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting the data fine except that your `username` property appears to be a concatenated string of two optionals (maybe `firstName.text` and `lastName.text`. So this will make it impossible to query. The first step is to unwrap these into a string:

```swift
let username = "\(firstName.text!) \(lastName.text!)"
```

Once you've done that, you can query for that data like this:

```swift
let username = "\(firstName.text!) \(lastName.text!)"
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(username)")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Now you can access the type value
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let type = value?["type"] as? String ?? ""
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

You may also want to reconsider having spaces in your property names (maybe use `lastName` instead of `last name`). It will be easier for your code later on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate the advice.